# typescript + operator usage on union types

Tags: typescript

I am trying to teach students the intricacies of things like polymorphism via (in this case built-in) operator overloading, and I created an example I thought should work but didn't. I would love some insight from Typescript experts as to why this example fails.

```
function add2(a: number) {
  return a + 2;
} // works fine, adds 2 and returns a number

function concat2(a:string) {
  return a + 2;
} // works fine, concatenates '2' and returns a string

function addOrConcatenateTwo(a: string | number) {
  return a + 2;
} 
// compile error. I THOUGHT it would return a string | number but it errors out no matter what.
```

I thought that Typescript would see that + is defined for strings and + is also defined for numbers and it would allow the last function to run. That's how it works for shared method names across interfaces, so why does the + operator work differently?

This works fine and does exactly what I thought my example above would do. Is this a bug? Admittedly, one that would likely only appear in artificial educational scenarios?

```
function addOrConcatenateTwo(a: string | number) {
    if (typeof (a) == "string") {
        return a + 2;
    } else {
        return a + 2;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57686313/how-does-typescript-operator-work-with-generics-and-functions/57696667#57696667) - especially second half - help you out? In essence the + operator does not work with union types.

Comment: It does! Well, sort of - it tells me that what I've discovered is, in fact, true, but it doesn't really address why. Is this a philosophical decision (and if so, what is the reasoning behind it) or just an implementation reality?

Comment: Cannot speak for the TS developers here, so just some speculations: I think, above is a very rare use case (in most cases you want to do a calculation *xor* a concatenation) and the team may have decided, that this construct is more likely to be an error according to [TS design goals](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals). Also it is stated that TS is not considered as 'sound or "provably correct' type system. Instead, strike a balance between correctness and productivity.", so that could be a point in favor of practicability.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12410#issuecomment-286590386) is a statment from one of the developers that goes in your diretion:
"T + T where T extends string | number is still disallowed -- we don't feel this is a good use case because whether you get concatenation or addition is not predictable, thus something that people shouldn't be doing." That can be even more transferred to a simple union type `string | number` like in above case. Instead it is [suggested](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12410#issuecomment-286860930) to e.g. use function overloads

Comment: Okay, so a (totally fair) philosophical decision. I even understand it! It just means I'll have to jump straight to method overloads to get into this idea, which is fine. I appreciate your time!