# Cannot add string | number to string | number types in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-typings

So, I have type alias `T` which represents `string | number` union type

if I try to add two variables with this type, I'll get variable with type `T`. But if I take these two variables as parameters of a function it will be an error:

```js
type T = string | number;

function add(a: T, b: T): T{
  return a + b; 
  // Error: Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T'.
}

let a: T = 1;
let b: T = 'foo';

const c = a + b; // But this is ok
```

Why I can't do that?

Comment: Exact duplicate of [typescript + operator usage on union types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58522766/typescript-operator-usage-on-union-types) (which doesn't have an answer unfortunately). See also [Operator '+' cannot be applied to types 'T' and 'T'. in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59802954/1048572) (where the titular `T` refers to a generic, not an alias, but the answer handles the same case)

Answer (score 0):

The error case here is `number` + `number | string`

You can verify that as the below function is not valid.

```
function addOne(x: number | string) {
  return 1 + x;
}
```

From the typescript [github page](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12410#issuecomment-286860930)

If `T extends string | number` then `T` can be `string | number` which means one value of type `T` can be `string` a different value of type `T` can be a `number`.

It really sounds like you should use **overloads** here rather than a type parameter.

Comment: But by that definition if both are numbers -- it's ok, if one number and one string -- it's ok. And when you trying to add number and number | string, only these two cases can happen. Seems like typescript not smart enough to figure that out