# Type guards TypeScript how it works?

Tags: typescript

I find an example to explain Type guards in Typescript but
I don't understand, why this code work:

```
function add(
   arg1:string|number,
   arg2:string|number
  ):any{
       if (typeof arg1==="string"){
           console.log("string")
           return arg1+arg2;  
        }
        if (typeof arg1==="number" && typeof arg2==="number"){
            console.log("number")
            return arg1+arg2;  
        }
        return arg1.toString()+arg2.toString()
}
console.log (add(1,2));
```

and why doesn't work, if you change the second if like this:

```
if (typeof arg1==="number" ){...
```

without the condition in and doesn't work 
even if this function work:

```
function add2():any{
    return (2+"3")
}
 console.log(add2())
```

So why I have to put the condition in and ? otherwise give an error?

Comment: Basically, although the `+` will definitely work in Javascript, its behaviour when `arg1` is a number depends on whether `arg2` is a string or a number; normally, when you write `+` you should know whether you want string concatenation or numeric addition, so Typescript reports an error when the `+` operator is ambiguous. The `add2` function has no error because the behaviour is definitely string concatenation, not ambiguous.

Comment: ok @kaya3 so why  in the first if it's work even without  the condition in and?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57686313/how-does-typescript-operator-work-with-generics-and-functions) help? Basically it is treated as safe to apply the `+` operator to `string|number` and `string`, but not when the operands are `string | number` and `number`. At least one has to be `string` (see the quotings from the specs in the answer).

Comment: In the first `if` statement, where `arg1` is definitely a string, then `+` is definitely string concatenation regardless of the type of `arg2`, so it's not ambiguous.

Comment: @ford04 not I don't understand even in your exaple in the tabelle  there is that number+string is allowed  ad return a string exactly as in my add2 function. so why I need the condition in and in the second if?